# Django Haystack queryset to django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-haystack

Here comes another problem from the Django-Haystack custom queryset.

How can I create a Django Rest Framework List View (or whatever view) that uses Django-Haystack's custom queryset attribute as a queryset?

The difference is basically that where the regular queryset attribute contains regular objects, the Django-Haystack's custom queryset contains a dictionary with an 'object' property that returns the object.

```
Queryset:
[<ModelInstance_1>, <ModelInstance_2>]

SearchQuerySet
[{object: <ModelInstance_1>}, {object: <ModelInstance_2>}]
```

I have searched before posting, and found a couple of answers but they are using outdated versions which work very differently than the way it works now.

I am currently using something like this:

```
class SearchProjectsView(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = ArchiveProjectSerializer
model = Project

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = []
    for result in SearchQuerySet().models(Project).filter(content=Clean(self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('q', ''))):
        queryset.append(result.object)
    return queryset
```

But as soon as I extend this with pagination or any other minor issue it will become a problem..

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to bump old thread, but I've written a library for this. Check out drf-haystack :)
https://github.com/inonit/drf-haystack